# How to use group by to get MAX, MIN, SUM values from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame below and I would like to get the MAX hourly temp, MIN hourly temp, and SUM hourly precip.  Here is my current code.  I want to print the MAX value for each `field id`.  What needs to be changed in my code to accomplish this?   Currently the code does not print the max value.  It prints the last value for `23:00`.  I would like for my output to look like this

[image]

```
import pandas
import pd as pandas

hrly_df = pd.DataFrame({'dateTime' :[t], 'field id': [id_], 'HourlyPrecipIn': [aPreVJ],'HourlyRH' : [aHumidVJ], 'HourlyTempF' : [aTempVJ]})

tempMax = hrly_df.loc[hrly_df.groupby('field id')['HourlyTempF'].idxmax()]
```

`dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 01:00:00    40238             0.0      73.8         48.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 02:00:00    40238             0.0      77.0         46.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 03:00:00    40238             0.0      79.9         47.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 04:00:00    40238             0.0      80.6         46.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 05:00:00    40238             0.0      82.6         45.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 06:00:00    40238             0.0      85.8         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 07:00:00    40238             0.0      80.2         46.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 08:00:00    40238             0.0      71.3         50.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 09:00:00    40238             0.0      69.8         50.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 10:00:00    40238             0.0      62.7         53.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 11:00:00    40238             0.0      62.2         54.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 12:00:00    40238             0.0      52.4         55.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 13:00:00    40238             0.0      50.9         57.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 14:00:00    40238             0.0      46.7         58.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 15:00:00    40238             0.0      47.8         57.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 16:00:00    40238            0.01      47.1         55.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 17:00:00    40238            0.04      61.1         52.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 18:00:00    40238            0.03      80.0         48.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 19:00:00    40238            0.04      88.1         46.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 20:00:00    40238            0.08      93.8         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 21:00:00    40238            0.07      93.0         45.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 22:00:00    40238            0.08      93.0         45.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 23:00:00    40238            0.09      92.7         45.1
Starting import of field id: 3402
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 01:00:00     3402             0.0      73.9         48.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 02:00:00     3402             0.0      77.1         46.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 03:00:00     3402             0.0      79.9         47.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 04:00:00     3402             0.0      80.6         46.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 05:00:00     3402             0.0      82.6         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 06:00:00     3402             0.0      85.6         45.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 07:00:00     3402             0.0      80.2         47.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 08:00:00     3402             0.0      71.3         50.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 09:00:00     3402             0.0      69.7         50.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 10:00:00     3402             0.0      62.8         53.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 11:00:00     3402             0.0      62.2         54.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 12:00:00     3402             0.0      52.6         55.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 13:00:00     3402             0.0      50.9         57.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 14:00:00     3402             0.0      46.8         58.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 15:00:00     3402             0.0      47.8         57.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 16:00:00     3402            0.01      47.2         55.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 17:00:00     3402            0.03      61.1         52.5
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 18:00:00     3402            0.03      79.9         48.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 19:00:00     3402            0.04      88.2         46.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 20:00:00     3402            0.08      93.7         45.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 21:00:00     3402            0.07      93.0         45.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 22:00:00     3402            0.07      93.0         45.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 23:00:00     3402            0.08      92.7         45.1
Starting import of field id: 45883
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 01:00:00    45883             0.0      75.4         48.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 02:00:00    45883             0.0      77.6         47.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 03:00:00    45883             0.0      79.6         47.3
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 04:00:00    45883             0.0      80.2         47.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 05:00:00    45883             0.0      82.5         45.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 06:00:00    45883             0.0      84.7         45.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 07:00:00    45883             0.0      79.2         47.2
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 08:00:00    45883             0.0      71.9         50.0
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 09:00:00    45883             0.0      68.9         51.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 10:00:00    45883             0.0      63.0         53.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 11:00:00    45883             0.0      61.8         54.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 12:00:00    45883             0.0      52.9         56.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 13:00:00    45883             0.0      50.9         57.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 14:00:00    45883             0.0      48.4         58.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 15:00:00    45883             0.0      48.3         57.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 16:00:00    45883            0.02      48.2         55.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 17:00:00    45883            0.07      63.0         52.4
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 18:00:00    45883            0.02      79.8         48.9
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 19:00:00    45883            0.05      89.4         47.1
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 20:00:00    45883            0.08      93.4         45.8
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 21:00:00    45883            0.07      93.2         45.6
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 22:00:00    45883            0.04      92.8         45.7
              dateTime field id  HourlyPrecipIn  HourlyRH  HourlyTempF
0  2019-05-21 23:00:00    45883             0.1      92.3         45.6`

Comment: Hello, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example this example here, it is difficult to actual understand what you're trying to achieve. Your example isn't minimal or and barely readable. More importantly it isn't verifiable. Please provide an example of what you expect the data to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for so I'll try my best until you can provide verification:

```py
hrly_df = {'dateTime': ['2019-05-21 01:00:00', '2019-05-21 02:00:00', '2019-05-21 03:00:00', '2019-05-21 01:00:00', '2019-05-21 02:00:00'],
           'field id': [40238, 40238, 40238, 3402, 3402],
           'HourlyPrecipIn': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           'HourlyRH': [73.8, 77.0, 79.9, 73.9, 77.1],
           'HourlyTempF': [48.4, 46.8, 47.0, 48.4, 46.8]}

hrly_df = pd.DataFrame(hrly_df)
# Gets you max 'HourlyTempF' per 'field id'
temp_max = hrly_df[['field id', 'HourlyTempF']].groupby('field id').max()
# Gets you min 'HourlyTempF' per 'field id'
temp_min = hrly_df[['field id', 'HourlyTempF']].groupby('field id').min()
# Gets you sum of 'HourlyPrecipIn' per 'field id'
precip_sum = hrly_df[['field id', 'HourlyPrecipIn']].groupby('field id').sum()

print(temp_max)
print(temp_min)
print(precip_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `agg` with function list

```
hrly_df.groupby('field id')['HourlyTempF'].agg(['min','max','sum'])
Out[313]: 
           min   max    sum
field id                   
3402      46.8  48.4   95.2
40238     46.8  48.4  142.2
```